# Half butter half shortening in overnight potato rolls?

Tags: substitutions, bread

I am making overnight potato rolls and have always used 2/3 cup of shortening. I was thinking that half butter half shortening might make my rolls even better. Will this idea help or hinder a yeast dough potato roll?

Comment: I removed your signature, just because we don't do that here.We are different from other internet sites, so I encourage you to take a look at our [tour](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help).  Welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Answer (score 3):

That should be fine. Potato and butter is a pretty solid flavor pairing! :) Know that butter contains some water (~15%) so you may want to adjust your liquid ingredients accordingly. That amount of butter contains about a teaspoon of water, so not enough to really worry about, but be aware. Use unsalted room temperature butter, and come back and tell us how it went!